# Postgres SQL attribution over time range

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using Postgres 11 and trying to figure out if I can do this in a single query.

Suppose I have two tables:

```
Event1
------
id
uuid
timestamp
```

```
Event2
------
uuid
timestamp
```

When I join these tables by `uuid`, `Event2` rows should be attributed to a particular `Event1.id` up to when a newer `Event1.id` is active.

For example, if I have these rows:

Event1:

```
id | uuid | timestamp
---------------------
10 | abc  | 2020-10-01 01:00:00
20 | abc  | 2020-10-01 02:11:00
30 | abc  | 2020-10-01 03:00:00
```

Event2:

```
uuid | timestamp
----------------
abc  | 2020-10-01 01:10:00
abc  | 2020-10-01 01:15:00
abc  | 2020-10-01 02:30:00
abc  | 2020-10-01 03:00:00
abc  | 2020-10-01 03:30:00
```

I would get:

```
id | uuid | timestamp
---------------------
10 | abc  | 2020-10-01 01:10:00
10 | abc  | 2020-10-01 01:15:00
20 | abc  | 2020-10-01 02:30:00
30 | abc  | 2020-10-01 03:00:00
30 | abc  | 2020-10-01 03:30:00
```

`Event1.id == 10` would get attributed `Event2` items from timestamp `01:00:00` until `02:10:59`. `Event1.id == 20` would get attributed `Event2` items from timestamp `02:11:00` until `02:59:59`. `Event1.id == 20` would get attributed everything after `03:00:00`.

Is this possible in SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to use window functions to get the "next" event for each row in event1, and then it's a simple join from there.

```sql
WITH time_window AS (
    SELECT id, uuid, timestamp as start, 
           lead(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY uuid ORDER BY timestamp) as end 
    FROM event1
)
SELECT time_window.id, time_window.uuid, event2.timestamp 
FROM time_window, event2 
WHERE time_window.uuid = event2.uuid 
AND event2.timestamp >= time_window.start 
AND (time_window.end IS NULL OR event2.timestamp < time_window.end);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html) in the PostgreSQL

It could be used in such use cases. For example:

```
create table ev1(id bigint, uuid text, ts timestamp);
insert into ev1 values
  (10, 'abc', '2020-10-01 01:00:00'),
  (20, 'abc', '2020-10-01 02:11:00'),
  (30, 'abc', '2020-10-01 03:00:00');

select * from ev1;
┌────┬──────┬─────────────────────┐
│ id │ uuid │         ts          │
├────┼──────┼─────────────────────┤
│ 10 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 01:00:00 │
│ 20 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 02:11:00 │
│ 30 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 03:00:00 │
└────┴──────┴─────────────────────┘

select *, tsrange(ts, lead(ts) over (partition by uuid order by id), '[)') as tsrange from ev1;
┌────┬──────┬─────────────────────┬───────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id │ uuid │         ts          │                    tsrange                    │
├────┼──────┼─────────────────────┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ 10 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 01:00:00 │ ["2020-10-01 01:00:00","2020-10-01 02:11:00") │
│ 20 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 02:11:00 │ ["2020-10-01 02:11:00","2020-10-01 03:00:00") │
│ 30 │ abc  │ 2020-10-01 03:00:00 │ ["2020-10-01 03:00:00",)                      │
└────┴──────┴─────────────────────┴───────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Note that the `[)` means "included the left bound and excluded the right bound", something like `value >= "left bound" and value < "right bound"`

Note2: Unbounded range like `tsrange("left bound", NULL, '[)')` means `value >= "left bound"` only so the last expression `["2020-10-01 03:00:00",)` will include anything started at `2020-10-01 03:00:00` and later

And for now you can to use [the range operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html) to join your other data with it:

```
with cte as (
    select
        *,
        tsrange(ts, lead(ts) over (partition by uuid order by id), '[)') as tsrange
    from ev1)
select *
from
    cte as ev1 join ev2 /* Event2 table in your example */
        on (ev1.uuid = ev2.uuid and ev2.timestamp <@ ev1.tsrange);
```

NB: It could be nice approach for the small amount of data, but it will **NOT** to use any indexes so it will be extremely slow on the huge amount of data. So think about to transform your DB schema to keep the ranges as it is, without window functions and any other runtime transformations.

Comment: that was a brilliant answer. i had never used these window functions before. always something new to learn. i gave the "answer" credit to the other answer because I needed to actually "partition by uuid order by timestamp" instead of the id. The sample data may have misled you into thinking the ids are increasing as time goes on when it may or may not be the case. My mistake. However, i gave you credit for such a well explained answer! thanks